# Align button text to top/center horizontal android

Tags: android

[image]

Hi, I have a button which looks like `img1`.

I need the button's text to be top/horizonal center like `img2`.

I tried using this

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/equalBtn2"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

But I get the result as `img3`.
I dont want the top spacing between the text and the button's head.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Button's parent XML

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="C"
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="&lt;"
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/equalBtn2"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you show the buttons parent XML?

Comment: Yes, added, please check.

Comment: You didn't add orientation to your linearlayout. [Not the solution]

Comment: I dragged and dropped horizontal, linear layout. So it worked as such. I did not mention the orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/equalBtn2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_exp_pressed"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@color/AliceBlue"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code (like badge style) : edit!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/myButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="0"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for this hack, but still, the textview's text is not visible for some reason. I although expect a proper answer for this.

Comment: add in textview this code.
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is by setting *minHeight="0dp"* and setting *android:paddingBottom="whatever dimension"* you like.

**Example:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:text="O"
    android:background="@color/yellow" />
```

*minHeight* removes the default *paddingTop* and *paddingBottom* of button. So you could manually set *paddingBottom* so that **text aligns to the top of the button.**

Comment: no doesn't help. It does not move the text up, if i increase the bottom padding. it crops the text

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom style into styles.xml

```
<style name="textTop">
    <item name="android:gravity">top|center</item>
</style>
```

And set this style to the button

```
<Button
    style="@style/textTop"
    .... />
```

And never set the `android:gravity` to the button, it will dismiss the top mentioned gravity in style